Earth Engine Double Slider
I'm trying to make a UI component similar to the ui.Slider() component in Earth Engine, but I need it to have two sliders, so it can define a range between two numbers.
I can make it work with two separate sliders calling the same update method, but it would be a much better user experience to have just one UI component with both sliders on the same line.
Here is some sample code using the out-of-the-box ui.Slider() component for reference:
https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/javascript/src/examples/UserInterface/CollectionSlider.js

I'm not sure how best to approach this, so I'm looking for guidance or a similar example I can emulate.

There's nothing built-in to let you do that.

Is it possible to build a custom javascript widget?

I think the best you can do inside EE is to have two sliders and have them update each other, to prevent invalid ranges. https://code.earthengine.google.com/ad9320aeb1e8c43568f361bdb5b7eb19
